# Dot product of vectors with matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have two vectors $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and use the dot product to calculate the angle $a\bullet b=\lambda$. But I need to transform the vector $\vec a$ with the matrix A. Is there a way to find a matrix B so that $(A\vec a \bullet B \vec b)=\lambda$ ?

Comment: Hi there, it would be beneficial if you would elaborate your question more. For example what kind of matrix is $A$ and $B$, like square matrices or not?. Also using dot product you cannot find the angle directly, unless $|a||b|=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write the inner product as $\mathbf{b}^{T}\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}$, then the question becomes what is $B$ such that $\mathbf{b}^{T}B^{T}A\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}$. This holds when $B^{T} = A^{-1}$, provided $A$ is invertible.